# Horizontal Scrolling an image by an amount defined by user

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to learn how to scroll an image horizontally. Say a user enters an integer amount, the returned image will then be a new image shifted by that amount to the left, and the left most pixels will appear on the right side of the image. I keep getting close to figuring this out, but am running into Out of Bounds errors.

Any ideas? I'm pretty new to Image Manipulation and processing.

Here's what I've written so far.

```
public void scrollHorizontal(int numpixels){
    horizontalscroll = new Picture(image6.getWidth(), image6.getHeight());

    for (int i = 0; i<image6.getWidth(); i++){
        for (int j=0; j<image6.getHeight(); j++){
            pix2 = image6.getPixel(i, j);
            horizontalscroll.setPixel(i-numpixels, j, pix2);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< image6.getWidth(); i++){
        for (int j = 0; j<image6.getHeight(); j++){
            pix2 = horizontalscroll.getPixel(i, j);
            horizontalscroll.setPixel(image6.getWidth()-numpixels-i ,j, pix2);
            //System.out.println(i);
        }

    }
    horizontalscroll.store("scrollhorizontal.gif");
}
```

The Picture class just creates a picture object based off of (x, y). 
getPixel() is a method of the Picture class. 'pix2' is a Pixel object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out after some more trial and error. Thanks. Just thought I'd share!

```
public void scrollHorizontal(int numpixels){ //allows the user to define numpixels to scroll horizontally by.
    int height = image6.getHeight();        //creates a new image that is scrolled horizontally by the entered numpixels amount.
    int width = image6.getWidth();
    horizontalscroll = new Picture(image6.getWidth(), image6.getHeight());
    for (int i = numpixels; i < width; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
            pix2 = image6.getPixel(i, j);
            horizontalscroll.setPixel(i-numpixels, j, pix2);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numpixels; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++){
            pix2 = image6.getPixel(i, j);
            horizontalscroll.setPixel((width-numpixels) + i, j, pix2);
        }
    }
    horizontalscroll.store("scrollhorizontal.gif"); //stores new picture object to a new file.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is at lines like this one:

```
horizontalscroll.setPixel(i-numpixels, j, pix2);
```

when i is less than numPixels, you are trying to set values at negative coordinates.

A correct solution would be:

```
public void scrollHorizontal(int numpixels){
  int wid = image6.getWidth();
  int hei = image6.getHeight();
  if (wid < Math.abs(numPixels)) {
    numPixels = numPixels % wid;
  }
  horizontalscroll = new Picture();
  if (numpixels >= 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i< hei; i++){
      for (int j = 0, h = wid - numPixels - 1; j < numPixels; ++j, ++h) {
        pix2 = image6.getPixel(i, h);
        horizontalscroll.setPixel(i, j, pix2);
      }
      for (int j = numPixels, h = 0; j< wid; ++j, ++h){
        pix2 = image6.getPixel(i, h);
        horizontalscroll.setPixel(i, j, pix2);
      }
    }
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i< hei; i++){
      for (int j = 0, h = numPixels; j< wid - numPixels - 1; ++j, ++h) {
        pix2 = image6.getPixel(i, h);
        horizontalscroll.setPixel(i, j, pix2);
      }
      for (int j = wid - numPixels, h = 0; j < wid; ++j, ++h) {
        pix2 = image6.getPixel(i, h);
        horizontalscroll.setPixel(i, j, pix2);
      }
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Time to crack open your debugger?